# Why is this not working?

Tags: php

I've this little script to send email! But it's not working... Firstly it says that my variables are not defined and then, they confirm me that the message has been sent, but it doensn't happen!

```
Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <form action="contactus.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" size="32" value="" name="name">
        </form> <br><br>
    E-Mail: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <form action="contactus.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" size="32" value="" name="header">
        </form> <br><br>
    Subject: &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <form action="contactus.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" size="32" value="" name="subject">
        </form> <br><br>
    Message: <br>
    <form action="contactus.php" method="POST">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message" value=""></textarea>
    </form>
    <br><br>

    <form action="contactus.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>


    <?php

    // php script to send emails 

    $to = 'some@email.com';

    if (isset ($_POST['message'])) {
        $message = "$name" . "<br><br>" . $_POST['message'];
    }


    if (isset ($_POST['header'])) {
        $header = "From:" . $_POST['header'];
    }


    if (isset ($_POST['subject'])) {
        $subject = ($_POST['subject']);
    }

    if (isset ($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = ($_POST['name']);
    } 




    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
    echo "Your message has been sent!";
    }



    //end of the php script

    ?>
```

If some of you can help me would be great!

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't work how? What happens when you submit the form? Do you get any errors? A whitescreen? Or something else?

Comment: You're **ASSUMING** the mail got sent, and don't even bother checking `mail()` return value. e.g. you're lying.

Comment: I feel like at least 10% of all Stack Overflow questions are questions about PHP mail forms that are missing details.

Comment: It says that the variables $subject $message and $header are not defined, and then the message "Your message has been sent" appears!

Comment: Am I missing something, or is the problem that he is using like 5 different `<form>` elements?  There are no inputs in the form that has the submit button.

Comment: @user3033680 The only criteria for showing your success message is the existence of `submit` in your `_POST` data (and it will be there if you click your Submit button). There's no reliance on whether `mail()` returned a success flag or not. So your success message is not necessarily going to be accurate.

Comment: Ok I fixed that stupid bug, that was saying that my variables weren't defined, but it is still not sending the email... Any tip?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use all those different `form` elements.  You are using 5 separate forms and the only one that is being submitted is the one with the `submit` button.

Thus, when the form is being submitted there `$_POST['submit']` is set, but none of the other ones exist.

So you need your HTML to be:

```
<form action="contactus.php" method="POST">
    Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" size="32" value="" name="name"><br><br>
    E-Mail: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" size="32" value="" name="header"><br><br>
    Subject: &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" size="32" value="" name="subject"><br><br>
    Message: <br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message" value=""></textarea><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and `contactus.php`:

```
<?php
$to = 'some@email.com';
if(isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_POST['header']) &&
   isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['submit']) &&
   @mail($to, $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], $_POST['header'])) {
    echo "Your message has been sent!";
}else{
    echo "There has been a problem.";
}
?>
```

Comment: The `mail()` call could still fail, but this code will still indicate that it was successful despite a possible failure.

Comment: @ajp15243 : I was just counting on the `mail()` function throwing an error, but I've fixed it so it works better.

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\Capital\contactus.php on line 355"

the line

if(isset($message = ($_POST['message']) && isset($header = ($_POST['header']) &&

Comment: @user3033680 : Oops, sorry.  Fixed that.

Comment: Still not receiving the email... :/

Comment: @user3033680 Do you get the success or failure message? Are you running this locally or on a server? Are you sure there's a mail server set up? Did you spell your e-mail address correctly?

Comment: success message, running locally, i don't know how to see if the mail server is setted up and my adress is correct

Comment: @user3033680 : You're local server is likely not set up correctly for mail.  Unless you know that you have a IMAP/POP3 server running, my advice is to test it online/live/on the real web.

Comment: Ok, thank I surely will and then give some feedback! ;) thank you all.

Comment: @user3033680 You can always test locally with a dummy SMTP server, like [DevNullSMTP](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DevNullSmtp.jsp). It won't actually send the e-mail, but it captures the e-mail and allows you to read its content. This is a good test to make sure your e-mail actually dispatches properly from your application code. Anything beyond that will be up to the server's e-mail system when live.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
    echo "Mail sent successfully.";
} else {
    echo "PHP's mail() function failed!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you have a Form element for each input elements?
You should put all of your elements in a Form together.